# Combine 2 mdx queries

Tags: mdx, olap

I have 2 MDX queries from the same cube. Both use the same measure but with different time sets (both the time sets are same dimension but different hierarchies).

I want to join them in the same table results, so it will present the 2 measures (cut by the different sets) and another time dimension (“Day of Week”) that also uses the same time dimension.
The queries can be run separately as follows:

```
   with member [Measures].[AVG_6_WEEKS] as 
     [Measures].[Number of Answered Comms] /6
    select 
    nonempty([Comm Date UTC].[Day of Week].children)
    on 0, 
    [Measures].[AVG_6_WEEKS]
    on 1 
    from (select {LASTPERIODS( 42,[Comm Date UTC].[Year Month Day].lastsibling.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild.prevmember )}
    on 0 from comms)

;
 with member [Measures].[Answered Comms] as 
 [Measures].[Number of Answered Comms] 
select 
nonempty([Comm Date UTC].[Day of Week].children)
on 0, 
[Measures].[Answered Comms]
on 1 
from (select {LASTPERIODS( 7,[Comm Date UTC].[Year Month 
Day].lastsibling.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild.prevmember )}
    on 0 from comms)
```

Can it be done? I always get an error that I can’t use the same time hierarchies in the query…
Any idea? Something like SQL were I can join 2 views?

Thank you

Yoni.

Answer (score 0):

The following MDX should do that:

```
with member [Measures].[AVG_6_WEEKS] as 
     Aggregate({LASTPERIODS( 42,[Comm Date UTC].[Year Month Day].lastsibling.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild.prevmember )},
               [Measures].[Number of Answered Comms] /6
              )
     member [Measures].[Answered Comms] as 
     Aggregate({LASTPERIODS( 7,[Comm Date UTC].[Year Month Day].lastsibling.lastchild.lastchild.lastchild.prevmember )},
               [Measures].[Number of Answered Comms]
              ) 
select 
nonempty([Comm Date UTC].[Day of Week].children)
on 0, 
{ [Measures].[AVG_6_WEEKS], [Measures].[Answered Comms] }
on 1 
from comms
```

I moved the context from the subselects in your queries to the member definition using the `Aggregate` function.

Comment: thank you Frank, but using this script causes an error in the result table:  Aggregated functions cannot be used on calculated members in the measures dimension.